# Some code that I don't understand

Tags: ruby

I don't understand the `while true`, together with the `name = gets(',').chomp(',')` and their relationship. To me, it seems like a infinite loop. Would anyone explain this?

```
 print "Enter your some more names separated by commas: "
 while true
   name = gets(',').chomp(',')
   puts "Hello #{name}"
 end
```

Comment: Did you try running it? It is an endless loop which just prompts for names indefinitely, and prints them out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we expect questioners to have a minimal understanding of the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* an infinite loop. This program will never end (except that it will crash on some input). Breaking it down:

```
while true
```

This is the start a while loop with a condition that is always true so it will loop forever over the code up to `end`.

```
name = gets(',')
```

See the [documentation for gets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets). If you just run this program directly, it will wait for a "line" of input on `STDIN` (the console/terminal). The input will be read up to the record separator, which is "," and the result will be assigned to the variable `name`.

```
.chomp(',')
```

`chomp` is a [method on String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) which removes the record separator from the end of the string (again, ',' in this case).

```
puts "Hello #{name}"
```

This prints the string "Hello #{name}" with the value of the `name` variable interpolated into the #{} placeholder.

```
end
```

This ends the while loop.

If you run this program and type "mary, angela, andy" and press Enter it will:

1. read "mary," from STDIN, `chomp` the "," off the end, and assign "mary" to the `name` variable.
2. print "Hello mary" to STDOUT.
3. loop back to the top, read "angela,", etc...
4. loop back to the top, and wait because there is not another record separator on STDIN.

If you then type "foo," and press enter, it will:

1. read "andy\nfoo," from STDIN, `chomp` the "," off the end, etc...
2. print "Hello andy\nfoo" to STDOUT

So it is a pretty lousy program given what it is ostensibly trying to do, but there you have it.